# Configure phase of angularJS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrapping

[image: AngularJS Inititalization]

What is going on in the configure phase of bootstrapping angular app. Unable to imagine it. Right now i am confused with providers. SO may be insight to configure phase help me understand whole process.As provider can be injected in config phase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An angular application uses services (`$http`, `$location`, etc.).

It's sometimes necessary to *configure* these services before using them. For example, the `$location` service has two modes of execution: the "normal" mode, and the "html5" mode. `$http` might need some headers configured before even sending its very first HTTP request.

To configure these services, Angular uses *providers*. Providers are objects whose role is to accept configuration options during the configuration phase, and then, once everything is set up, to create the unique instance of a service.

So, to configure the `$location` service, you use its `$locationProvider` during the configuration phase. Once that phase is done, Angular, during the run phase, will call the provider's `$get()` method, which will create and return the `$location` service (hence the name "provider").