# $http interceptor is causing an infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, http, promise, infinite-loop

I'm building an AngularJs app working with a custom API, the latter needs a valid authorization token, if it isn't, my API returns a 4O1 HTTP status code.

Thus, I use a http interceptor which is meant to ask for a new token before retrying the previous request.

```
    app.factory('httpResponseErrorInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector, $http) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // should retry
                let deferred = $q.defer();
                let $http = $injector.get('$http');
                $.ajax({
                    url        : PUBLIC_API_URI,
                    type       : 'HEAD',
                    beforeSend : function(request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', api_access_key);
                    },
                    success    : function(result, status, xhr) {
                        console.log("error -> ok : should retry");
                        deferred.resolve(xhr.getResponseHeader('Authorization'));
                    },
                    error      : function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log("error -> bad : should give up");
                        deferred.resolve(null);
                    }
                });
                console.log(deferred.promise);
                if(deferred.promise == null)
                    return $q.reject(response);
                response.config['Authorization'] = api_access_key = deferred.promise;
                return $http(response.config);
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}]);
```

I used JQuery.ajax in my interceptor because I guessed that using $http was causing the infinite loop when the token-renewal request resulted in an error. 
But it still causes an infinite loop on error :
original-request -> renewal-request ...

Answer (score 2):

i don't see the complete log of the error but i guess the problem could be related to the injection of `$http` service (that is still there even if you're using $.ajax) inside an http interceptor. this will cause a circular dependency because angular will face an infinite loop trying to resolve both the dependency of `$http` and its interceptor.

see my previous answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895283/angular-error-injectorcdep-circular-dependency-when-using-factory-in-app-js/43896078#comment74834668_43896078)

if you need to make an ajax call try injecting the service "by need"

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('interceptor', function($injector){

  return {
      'responseError': function(response) {
         var http = $injector.get('$http');
         http.get..
       }
  }

});
```